# Boot issue with ASUS K55A - Black Screen

Tags: windows-8, bios

A friend asked me to look at a problem on their laptop.

The laptop is an ASUS with model # K55A-HI5103D running Win 8. It started getting an error on boot about having an issue with a PXE utility?? Walked them through getting to the BIOS and changed the boot order to have Windows Boot Manager be first in the boot order. As soon they saved and rebooted the computer, it now goes to a black screen with no splash screens and no BIOS display.

I have researched the web and appears this has happened to several people (exact same sequence of events). I have tried pulling the laptop battery, removing the AC power and holding the power button several times. Pulled the CMOS battery and left it out overnight, tried using a USB stick that is flashed as a boot device, and no luck. FYI I have tried tapping and holding every key known to get in the BIOS (F2, F10, DEL, ESC, etc.) and no luck. Nothing on the screen to indicate it is trying to boot. The power light stays on and the HD light flashes, can hear the optical drive spin up when first powered up.

This laptop was at least showing the BIOS and getting an error on a boot device until a change was made in the BIOS, so I would not think it is a hardware failure. From what I have read most of the time this has happened after an update to Windows 8. I know Windows 8 controls the BIOS differently now with UEFI computers and this one is a little over a year old so out of warranty.

Does anyone have ideas of what to try?

Comment: Windows 7 supported UEFI so in that regard not a great deal has changed.  At this point I would contact ASUS for technical support.

Comment: __Connect to an external monitor via VGA.__ - I had this happen a few weeks ago, and like you tried everything under the sun aside from this (because I didn't have an external monitor and also couldn't believe this was the answer when clearing the BIOS wasn't working.  (Sorry for the answer as comment, but my rep is too low since this is protected)

Answer (score 0):

I would try disconnecting the hard drive, labelling it clearly and putting it somewhere safe. If that gets me into the BIOS, i would try putting in a new harddisk and installing Windows to that. Then I would put the old drive into a usb docking station and try to read the data off it.

Answer (score 0):

> Walked them through getting to the BIOS and changed the boot order to
>   have Windows Boot Manager be first in the boot order. As soon they
>   saved and rebooted computer, it now goes to a black screen with no
>   splash screens and no BIOS display.

This sounds all too familiar. User edits BIOS settings, saves, exits, is greeted by the infamous black screen.

The changes made are somehow incompatible/hanging your system. Since your system appears to be unresponsive, you'll have to revert to the original factory BIOS settings (default settings).

I understand your system boots to a "black screen with no splash screens and no BIOS display".

You somehow need to reset the settings. I will share a close guarded secret hack to help you "reset" the changes made to your BIOS.

Clearing the CMOS on your motherboard will reset your BIOS settings to their factory defaults.

There are a few ways to clear the CMOS on your motherboard, but the most common is to remove the CMOS battery and install it in the opposite way "upside down", "reversed" for a few seconds then re-install the battery the right way. After clearing the CMOS, you'll need to access the BIOS setup utility and reconfigure your hardware settings.

This is considered a "hard reset" and helps recover from forgotten BIOS passwords, system hangs etc.

Good luck.